# School assignment and keep getting this error message "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException"

Tags: java, exception, import, java.util.scanner

1. I keep receiving the below error message when trying to run my code
2. for a school homework assignment based on from what I researched it has to do with the data being gather from my file.
3. Any help on how to fix this error would be much appreciated.
4. The file I am pulling from has a class with the teachers last name followed by the total sales for each class.

```js
package programFivePackage;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SchoolFruitClass 
{
 private int [] quantity;
 private String [] name;
 private int numClasses;
 
 public SchoolFruitClass (int size)
 {
  numClasses = size;
  quantity = new int [size];
  name = new String [size];
 }
 
 public void getData() throws IOException
 {
  Scanner input = new Scanner (new FileReader("fruit.txt"));
  
  numClasses = input.nextInt();
  String emptyString = input.nextLine();
  for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
  {
   name[i] = input.nextLine();
   quantity[i] = input.nextInt();

  }
 }
 
 public void displaySales()
 {
  System.out.println("The total fruits sold for each class is:");
  System.out.println("Class Name              Total Sold");
  for (int i = 0; i > 25; i++)
   System.out.println(name[i] + "           \t" + quantity[i]);
 }

}


package programFivePackage;
import java.io.*;
public class SchoolFruitClassDemo 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
 {
  SchoolFruitClass FruitSales = new SchoolFruitClass(26);

  FruitSales.getData();
  FruitSales.displaySales();
 }

}


OUTPUT Error:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at programFivePackage.SchoolFruitClass.getData(SchoolFruitClass.java:26)
 at programFivePackage.SchoolFruitClassDemo.main(SchoolFruitClassDemo.java:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

nextLine will read at the end of the line which includes sales also, that's why you are getting  InputMismatchException at nextInt...try to use next() instead of nextLine()

if you have spaces in name then do this

```
String line = input.nextLine();
String [] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
name[i]= tokens[0];
quantity[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
```